# java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone. MySQL 8

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timezone

Использую MySQL 8 на ОС Windows 10. версия коннектора 8.0.12. Создаю простое подключение к базе:

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class TestConnection {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Connection connection = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

                StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

                url.
                        append("jdbc:mysql://").
                        append("localhost:").
                        append("3306/").
                        append("test?").
                        append("user=root&").
                        append("password=root");

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url.toString());

            } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

В итоге получаю:
`java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Ôèíëÿíäèÿ (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.`

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить или подскажите куда копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно сунуть текст ошибки в Google Translate, чтобы понять куда копать. Ну и кракозябры могли бы навести на мысль. Вам сервер MySQL использует какую-то ересь вместо часового пояса.

Правильный способ - это [исправить настройки MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html):

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Moscow';
```

Более простой - задать часовой пояс на уровне устанавливаемого подключения, передав в URL соответствующий параметр

```
url.append("jdbc:mysql://")
   .append("localhost:")
   .append("3306/")
   .append("test?")
   .append("user=root&")
   .append("password=root")
   .append("serverTimezone=UTC");
```

Comment: Это решило вопрос. Правда еще пришлось добавить useSSL=false.